# How to check if the XML document has the tag "id" or not

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I am trying to find out if a tag "id" exists in my data or not.
I have a loop which will run for 500310 times to fetch the details of photos from Flickr. From these details, I fetch the id and owner id of the photo. Now, I am using this "id" with another method to fetch the geo details of the photo. But the problem is if some photo does not have the attribute "id". 
So, could anyone tell how can I check if attribute "id" exists for every photo or not?
After using the method flickr.photos.search():
we get the data like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="1" pages="2002" perpage="250" total="500310">
<photo id="35943698814" owner="21013862@N08" secret="b6d4735e47" 
server="4356" farm="5" title="Praha" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" 
/>
</photos>
</rsp>
```

[below is the link of image which contains code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf76x.jpg)

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Do not post *images* of code, but the code itself!

Answer (score 0):

If we use `BeautifulSoup`, we can use `has_attr` to check if `all(..)` `<photo>`s have an `id`:

```
if all(photo.has_attr('id') for photo in y.find_all('photo')):
    # all photos have an id
    pass
else:
    # there are photos without an id
    pass
```

You can of course also use the `.has_attr('id')` on a specific photo to check if it has such an `id`. Like for instance:

```
for photo in y.find_all('photo'):
    if photo.has_attr('id'):
        # the specific <photo> has an id
        pass
    else:
        # the specific <photo> has no id
        pass
```